# update chekbox value in mongodb collection with node js

Tags: node.js

this is route

```
.post('/update', function (req, res, next) { 
    var id=JSON.stringify(req.body.id);
    var value=JSON.stringify(req.body.value);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(value);
    var update_stock=stmodel.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{approve:value});
    update_stock.exec(function(err,doc){
      if(err) throw err;
});

function approvestock(id,value){
    console.log("helooo"+id);
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/update',
        method:'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data:{id:id,value:value},
        success:function(data){
            console.log("id");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    // $.get( "/update", function(data) {
    // });
        };
```

ejs file:

```
 <% let chk = row.approve ? 'checked' : '' %>
     <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="approve"  onclick="approvestock('<%= row._id %>','<%= row.approve %>')"
 <%= chk %> />
```

Comment: Can you show your schema?

Comment: approve:{
      type: Boolean, default: false
    }